# TYPO3 model validation

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x

Controller:

```
    /**
     * @param \Mvnaz\Corn\Domain\Model\BookedDate|null $book
     * @validate $book
     */
    public function newBookFormAction(\Mvnaz\Corn\Domain\Model\BookedDate $book = null)
    {
        $userList = $this->userRepository->buildList();
        if($book){
//            $user = $book->getUser();
//            $book->setSortCsvIndex($user->getCornSortCsvIndex());

        }

        else
            $book = new BookedDate();

        $this->view->assign("book", $book);
        $this->view->assign("userList", $userList);
    }
```

Model fields:

```
 /**
     * @var float
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $volume;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $sortCsvIndex;

    /**
     * @var \Mvnaz\Corn\Domain\Model\User
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $user = null;
```

if I use follow view fields validating is working, error class added to input and error text shown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="volume">
        <f:translate key="volume"/>
    </label>
    <f:form.textfield property="volume" class="form-control" id="volume" />
    <f:render partial="ValidatingErrors" arguments="{field: 'book.volume'}"/>
</div>


<label for="date">
    <f:translate key="date"/>
</label>
<div class='input-group date' id='date-picker-admin'>
    <f:form.textfield property="date" class="form-control" id="date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

if I add this field, validation not working:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">
        <f:translate key="user"/>
    </label>
    <f:form.select property="user" options="{userList}" id="user" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

I am confused, I tried everything! Also I noticed if I don't pass userList - validation works! I understood where is a problem. Object BookedDate contains object User, but User contains Storage of BookedDates. This breaks validation. How solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

1. For Extbase actions you need PHPDoc blocks before it to describe the arguments. Your functions are blank
2. In your Fluid template you need the `<f:validationResults>` part, described here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Form/ValidationResults.html
3. Read this documentation of validation carefully: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html

Comment: thank u for the help. I updated the post, not luck ((

Comment: I updated my answer for a good documentation about validation.

Comment: ok, I deleted that post and updated current, because now I know the cause in more details. Thank u so much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84475 This is the answer. My problem happened because I have circular relations, and typo3 validator stoped validate the same property after it was validated in other child object.

ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects']['TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Validation\\Validator\\GenericObjectValidator'] = array(
    'className' => 'Mvnaz\\Corn\\Xclass\\GenericObjectCustomValidator'
);
```

Classes\Xclass\GenericObjectCustomValidator.php:

```
<?php
namespace Mvnaz\Corn\Xclass;

/*
 * This file is part of the TYPO3 CMS project.
 *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License, either version 2
 * of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!
 */

use \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\ObjectAccess;

/**
 * A generic object validator which allows for specifying property validators
 */
class GenericObjectCustomValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\GenericObjectValidator
{
    /**
     * Checks if the given value is valid according to the validator, and returns
     * the Error Messages object which occurred.
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value that should be validated
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result
     * @api
     */
    public function validate($value)
    {
        $this->result = $this->result ?: new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result();
        if ($this->acceptsEmptyValues === false || $this->isEmpty($value) === false) {
            if (!is_object($value)) {
                $this->addError('Object expected, %1$s given.', 1241099149, [gettype($value)]);
            } elseif ($this->isValidatedAlready($value) === false) {
                $this->isValid($value);
            }
        }

        return $this->result;
    }

}
```